# Trigonometry inequation with cotangent

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, inequality

[image: inequation]

The second term equals $-\tan x$ and for the 3rd term I used the identity of $\cot(a+b)$. I obtain $\sqrt{3}\cot^3 x+3\cot^2 x-3\sqrt{3}\cot x-1$ How can I factorize this and solve the inequation?

Comment: I edited your post. Hope I didn't make anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks for adjusting the subject but why did you remove polynomial?

Comment: @counter It wasnt me. I readded the tag polynomials.

Comment: ah ok thank you.

Comment: Taussig What tutorial?

Comment: BPP you changed the subject again or it's not u? I meant it is inequation.

Comment: @counter Someone keeps changing inequation to inequality. I had the same problem a few days ago.

Comment: Why? We studied chaptre inequality at the year beginning. I dont have it for exam.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Wrong link. Wouldn't be awesome if schools teach latex.

Comment: Respectfully, ‘CTG’ should have been edited out in favor of ‘cot’. And no need for the image instead of text.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - your link shows the image, not the tutorial.

Comment: @counter My apologies.  I should have linked to this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the formula for $\cot(a+b)$, let us use
$$\cot a+\cot b=\dfrac{\sin(a+b)}{\sin a\sin b}$$
$\cot x+\cot(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=\dfrac{\cos 2x}{\sin x\cos x}=2\cot(2x)$

We obtain 
$2\cot (2x)+2\cot(x+\frac{\pi}{3})=2\left(\cot (2x)+\cot(x+\frac{\pi}{3})\right)$. Use the same identity on the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the identity $\cot3x=\dfrac{\cot^3x-3\cot x}{3\cot^2x-1}$.

Comment: Can we solve it without this identity? We didnt  take it in the course.

Comment: You can prove it by writing $\cot2x=\cot(x+x)$ and then $\cot3x=\cot(2x+x)$.